# urllib3 - PoolManager.Request - POST - Returns Empty

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

I am having an issue with urlli3. Please see code:

```
import urllib3
import certifi

#Setup urllib3 PoolManager
httpManager = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',ca_certs=certifi.where())

url = 'https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html/'
headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(
    keep_alive=True,
    user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6',
    accept_encoding=True
    )

params = {
     'emailOrNickname': 'username',
     'password': 'password',
     'rememberMe': 'true',
     '_rememberMe' : 'on',
     'targetUrl' : 'L15udS9JWHhHMURBNmdjdkFuTFJJeUR3PT0-',
     'submit': 'SignInButton'
     }

f = httpManager.request('POST', url, headers=headers, encode_multipart=False)
#f = httpManager.request('POST', url, fields=params, headers=headers, encode_multipart=False)
page = f.data.decode('utf-8')'
```

The return page (f, in code) returns an empty string. Can someone help me debug this please.

The error code I keep getting is 401. Authentication Error. I thought it could be a basic_authentication error but The website says it uses POST method. Could it be that I'm not adding value for the submit button? Do i need to add data for the submit? Coudl you provide details on that?

Thanks,

Comment: `f` is an empty string or `page` is? `f` should be an HTTPResponse. `page` might be empty if there was no data returned. You also need to look at the response status code on `f`.

Comment: The error code I keep getting is 401. Authentication Error. I thought it could be a basic_authentication error but The website say it uses POST method.

Could it be that I'm not adding value for the submit button? Do i need to add data for the submit? Coudl you provide details on that?